# Parsing XML before Javascript function executes

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have an external XML file that I want to parse using Javascript but, before another Javascript function executes. I want to store values from the XML file in a global object. The problem is that I am parsing my XML asynchronously as synchronous parsing is deprecated. The Javascript function executes before the XML is parsed, so I get an error because the global variables are `undefined`.

I tried calling the function that parses the XML file in one Javascript file, then calling the function in another file using the `defer` attribute. But this does work because the parser still executes after all scripts are executed. I am stumped! I have also tried using the `setTimeout()` method on the Javascript function but, that also produces undefined values in the end.

I have read several questions on stack overflow that have to do with the order in which scripts are executed. I will say that this problem has taught me a lot about execution order.

NOTE: There is much more to my scripts than shown here so I just added the bare essentials to illustrate how I am parsing my XML file and that the values get stored as undefined.

UPDATE: I have written the parser this way so that I can use in a neutral way. The parser is used many times and each time different events happen depending on the use. That is why I am not adding specific functions to the `onreadystatechange` function.

I am using `XML DOM` and `XMLHttpRequest` to parse my XML file.

```
// Parser
function load_prs( data_func , loc , tag )
{
var parsreq = new XMLHttpRequest() ;

parsreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
if ( (parsreq.readyState === 4) && (parsreq.status === 200) )
   {
   var xml = parsreq.responseXML ;
   var listing = xml.getElementsByTagName(tag) ;
   var list = listing[0].children ;

   // Call a specific function using the data_func argument
   data_func(list) ;
   }
} ;

parsreq.open("GET" , loc + ".xml" , true) ;
parsreq.send() ;
}
```

Call the function to parse:

```
load_prs(load_playlist , "nd/playlist" , "playlist") ;
```

The function `load_playlist()` assigns the XML values to a global object:

```
// The global object with name/value pairs
var playlist_obj = { band: "" , album: "" , title: "" } ;

// Array for storing playlist_obj
var playlist = [] ;

// Function to get values from the XML document
function get_val( tar , tag ) { return tar.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ; }

// Function passed to load_prs()
function load_playlist( list )
{
var px ;
var plen = list.length ;

// Loop through each item in the XML document and get values
for ( px = 0 ; px < plen ; px++ )
   {
   playlist_obj.band = get_val(list[px] , "band") ;
   playlist_obj.album = get_val(list[px] , "album") ;
   playlist_obj.title = get_val(list[px] , "title") ;

   // Push playlist_obj to the global array for later use
   playlist.push(playlist_obj) ;
   }
}
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist>
<track>
   <band>Desecresy</band>
   <album>Stoic Death</album>
   <title>Funeral Odyssey</title>
</track>
<track>
   <band>Catacombs</band>
   <album>In the Depths of R'lyeh</album>
   <title>Where No Light Hath Shone...</title>
</track>
</playlist>
```

When I try to call another function that accesses the global object in the same script, I get undefined values. `var t` returns `undefined` because `load_band()` is executed before `load_prs()`.

```
load_prs(load_playlist , "nd/playlist" , "playlist") ;
function load_band() { var t = playlist[0].band ; }
load_band() ; // var t returns undefined
```

Comment: Another thing to point out. Once all scripts are finished executing, the parser works and stores values in the global object. But I need it to happen before the `load_band` function is called not after. When the `load_band` function is called I get an error.

Comment: Well, you have to move that `load_band()` into your code in the onreadystatechange handler respectively the code called from there. In general, these days you should look into Promises to ease such a task.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Wow, I never looked at it that way. Sometimes I get so caught up in it all I fail to overlook something so simple. lol

Comment: @Martin Honnen I will try that approach now and see.

Comment: @Martin Honnen It is worth mentioning something else. Your comment has got me thinking about lots of ideas. The problem is the `load_prs()` function is used many times and used in a loop that compares the values of the playlist XML with another XML. When there is a match, a boolean value is declared true. This process happens inside a loop. I don't want to simply add specific functions to the `onreadystatechange` function because I need it to be accessible as a neutral parser. That way I can just parse, get the values, then do specifics with them depending on the task.

Comment: @Martin Honnen In other words, the parser is used in several different situations. That is why I am passing a function to the parser. One function is `load_playlist`, but there are others as well.

Comment: If `load_playlist` creates the global data, you will need to make sure your function `load_band` is called from or after `load_playlist`. Promises are one way to do that.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Wow, I just read an article on Promises! They sound very promising! lol.... One way or the other, I think you will have answered my question in the end. As soon as I get a working example, I will give you the answer for this question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Martin Honnen Okay well I got it all figured out. I want to give you the answer but not sure how. What I did was added each load_prs function inside itself instead of using loops and used a global variable to count. I made sure every action was called inside the parser's argument functions.

Comment: Just a note, synchronous resource **fetching** is deprecated, parsing is done synchronously.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes I know. I pointed that out in my first paragraph. I think you meant to say: "parsing is done asynchronously".

Comment: @Xavier no no I meant to say what I said. Fetching (i.e getting the data) is async, but parsing (i.e reading the data and building a DOM tree from it) is synchronous. In xhr you won't notice it, but e.g a DOMParser will parse the data synchronously.

Comment: @Kaiido Anyway, I already solved the problem by calling all of my functions inside the `load_prs()` function. See answer.

Comment: @Kaiido Ahhh, I see your point now. Very good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wanted to give Martin Honnen the answer but, he seems to be unavailable. So I am going to answer myself. But Martin Honnen did answer my question (look in comments). While `Promises` would have been a great solution, I felt that the answer could have been simpler without the need to add more code and make the situation more complex than it already is.

So the answer was actually quite simple. By adding the `load_band()` function directly into the `load_playlist()` function, my variables got their values in the order I wanted. I just had to make sure that all functions called were called from the functions that were passed to the parsing function. I had to rewrite my code extensively but, it was worth it. Now my `load_prs()` function can be used many times, as a neutral function. It gets the values and can then do different things with those values, depending on the intent, with the specific function that is passed to it. Now the example looks like this:

```
function load_playlist( list )
{
var px ;
var plen = list.length ;
for ( px = 0 ; px < plen ; px++ )
   {
   playlist_obj.band = get_val(list[px] , "band") ;
   playlist_obj.album = get_val(list[px] , "album") ;
   playlist_obj.title = get_val(list[px] , "title") ;
   playlist.push(playlist_obj) ;
   }
load_band() ;
}

function load_band() { var t = playlist[0].band ; }
load_prs(load_playlist , "nd/playlist" , "playlist") ;
```

NOTE: When I got this example to work, I discovered that my `playlist` array had objects that were all identical. This was because I was using a global object with name value pairs and trying to give it different values at different times.

```
var playlist_obj = { band: "" , album: "" , title: "" }
```

I was able to solve this by using the object constructor.

```
// Object constructor
function pobj( b , a , t )
{
this.band = b ;
this.album = a ;
this.title = t ;
}

// Create local variables
var band = get_val(list[px] , "band") ;
var album = get_val(list[px] , "album") ;
var title = get_val(list[px] , "title") ;

// The new keyword creates a new object
playlist_obj = new pobj(band , album , title) ;

// Store the new object in the global array
playlist.push(playlist_obj) ;
```